# What are the differences between structures and files?

Tags: c

I have been learning C for 8 months at my university,studying at home too, I would like to improve myself.At the moment,I am on the "FILE" subject.What are the differences between structures and files?Do we create things like in structures?Do we store data like in structs?Note that I know things about structures.

Comment: Wait, how are they similar?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What kind of structures do you mean? The only thing that I associate with structures in C are `struct`s, which are not connected to `FILE` in any way

Comment: @Binary_10 I am asking about writing new files,reading files and append files.I am not expert on it yet,I already asked if you would help on it.

Comment: `structures (struct)` are user defined data types in c programming, which can be used to hold specific data as a collection during program execution. they are not related to the `files` on storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, `structs` are a special datatype that consists of a group of variables that can be referenced by a single pointer.

`FILE` is a special kind of `struct`, it's usually used as a pointer to a file object on disk.

```
FILE *fp;
char *mode = "r";

fp = fopen("myfile.txt", mode);

if (fp == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

You can see it defined in stdio.h, it might look something like this depending on your compiler.

```
typedef struct _iobuf
{
    char*   _ptr;
    int _cnt;
    char*   _base;
    int _flag;
    int _file;
    int _charbuf;
    int _bufsiz;
    char*   _tmpfname;
} FILE;
```